# Route the traffic through other system

Tags: networking, routing, nat

Im fairly new with this. I wondering if i have 3 systems linux (e.g system A, system B and system C) and i want to redirect all the traffic through the system B, it may be looks like this:

```
System A <-----> System B <-----> System C
```

so if I want to ping from system A to system C, on system C when i dump the ping it would be written ping from system B. Is it possible to do?

**UPDATE**

after getting some advice so the NAT would be the answer of my case. This is the detail of the system: (let say we keep using port 80 for the system)

```
System A <-----> System B <-----> System C 
   VPN          VPN Strongswan   Normal System
192.168.x.x     10.184.x.x       10.48.x.x
```

Comment: What you're asking for (concealing the IP address of A from C) isn't routing.  Routing would simply ensure that A and C could communicate through B.  You might be thinking of NAT?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried NAT before for forwarding the traffic but there is seems no clear way to solve my problem. With my case, can you suggest the best way to do NAT?

Comment: The answer is indeed nat. What exactly did you state in your nat attempt, and what are the IP addresses of A, b (and b1 if appropriate) and c?  What does a tracerpute ftomba to be show?

Comment: Hi @davidgo , Thank you for your answer. I've done update the question with example IP address. like what Slartibartfast said, I want to forward the traffic and concealing the IP address. I'm so sorry I don't understand what traceroute ftomba should be show, all I can tell you just the description above. Can you suggest me the way to do NAT with this?

Comment: Cant help you based on what you have provided.    You did not provide a traceroute and your assertions about IP addresses for System A, B and C are nonsequiters (as IP addresses generally bind to interfaces - so B should have more then 1 IP address, relatedly because IP addresses of adjoining segments have addresses in the same range).

Comment: Thank you again for your reply @davidgo . Can you please give me the example of a traceroute and assertions about IP address? and what supposed I read for this case?

Comment: Sorry, I'm voting to close this. Traceroutes are network 101 stuff.  We don't do learning  recommendations here. Simply put, you have at least a few weeks of learning before you are qualified to ask the question. Maybe look for a Udemi course or watch some videos on routing.